# scheduling multiple tasks on windows scheduler

Tags: powershell

If I have multiple processes to schedule, can I do it all at once (some kid batch), or do I just need to "time it"?  For example,  I'm trying to automate a report which requires 2 tasks:

## 1. I  need to schedule the script to run the SQL query to get the data.  Then,

## 2. I run another script using powershell to update the report with the SQL data.

My current process is to schedule #1, and then I schedule #2 to run 20 minutes or so after #1 so #1 has time to complete.  Imagine if I have 10 reports to update in 1 day,  I will need to time each task.

Is this the best way to do it, or is there like an easier way?  In my mind, I imagine I can run #1 as a batch, and then I can also run #2 as a batch and it will all just update together.

thoughts?

Comment: Why not edit the script to combine "step 1" with "step 2" using the output of step 1. ie: combine the scripts to use the data from "step 1" as the data used in step 2?

Comment: Thanks jake.  Are you saying to write one script that will do both 1 and 2?  If so,  I don't really know where or how to do that.  Right now,  my step 1 is simply:  "run sql query and output to csv" with task scheduler. My step 2 is "open powershell and run powershell  script" which opens an excel file and runs a bunch of VBA.  I'm not really familiar with writing scripts.  Just to clarify,  I'm not writing any scripts to do the task.  I'm just using windows task scheduler to open and run said codes.  If there is a way to write a 'master' script that calls #1 and #2,  I'm open to it

Comment: In this case, if the scripts are opaque things you aren't the author of or you cant reproduce with your own custom script, then this is more complicated. What I suggested was to "skip the csv step", meaning that you use the data you would export to csv instead directly as the input to step 2. But, as you commented, this is not possible in your situation

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at this site? [Scripting Guy! Blog](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2010/11/01/use-powershell-to-collect-server-data-and-write-to-sql/)
I think this blog post is something that you are looking for. If you can try to script some of it, we can help you out more.